# binomial calculation method

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I want solve this probability: For
$p= 0.4$
$q=0.8$
$n= 20$

$1-P(5<x<11)$

=

$1-\sum_{k=6}^{10} \binom{20}{k}(0.4)^k(0.6)^{20-k}. Wolfram Alpha -> = 0,2531$

Is calculation method right?

And is there a way to solve this in a hand calculator e.g. CASIO fx-991ES?

Comment: Subtract the value of your sum from 1, as you indicated above. Also, check your $q$ value... (I changed your first equation to what I thought you wanted.)

Comment: That formula involves nothing more complicated than addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, so if your calculator can do the four arithmetic operations, it ought to be able to evaluate that sum.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is good, I think. But there is a typo that q=0.8. And you can do it with your calculator. 
Just use the sum from right hand top corner, and the C(p,n) function at right hand bottom corner to generate the sum you want.